# How should I diagnose an HTTP request 500 that appears to be related to Authorizers in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am brand new to AWS API Gateway/AWS Lambda/AWS Amplify. I have a React Native application that I am trying to use AWS Amplify to make an API call and issue a PUT request, which would then cause the API Gateway to invoke my AWS Lambda function. When I create the AWS Amplify API endpoint, I don't see a command line option to define a PUT method. The default is "Any", which works, but I would like to specify a PUT method specifically. When I add in a PUT method manually on the API Gateway website and then call it from my React Native front end, I get...

Error: Request failed with status code 500

Looking at the API Gateway responses, this is due to either an "Authorizer Configuration Error" or an "Authorizer Failure", so I am assuming the problem is not with my front end code but with the configuration of "authorizers" on the API Gateway. What are authorizers? How do they relate to making an API call? And what steps can I take to troubleshoot what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lambda, a Cognito User Pool or an IaM role as an Authorizer. The short version is that your API endpoints can either be open and public or have an Authorizer, if they have an authorizer then they have to be setup correctly. It is set through the API Gateway config for an endpoint in the Method Request section.

AWS Lambda authorizer info:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

AWS Cognito Info:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html